# Jprofiler - Jprofiler is taking lot of CPU and memory while recording CPU

Tags: jprofiler

Jprofiler is taking lot of CPU and memory while recording CPU. We are using v9.1

Sometimes it gets hanged, CPU touches 95% and memory 80%. Data is not getting loaded in the Record CPU.

Also once when we were able to record, the saved snapshot file size is around 60 to 75 MB. Please suggest the reason for this memory size.

Answer (score 0):

> the saved snapshot file size is around 60 to 75 MB. Please suggest the reason 
>   for this memory size.

Probably you're recording far too many method invocations. Please have a look at the filter settings and restrict the filters.

Also, switch to "Sampling" which has a lot lower overhead than "Instrumentation". If there are glitches in the UI, there should be an exception in %TEMP%\jprofiler_error.log or $TMP/jprofiler_error.log.